# Javascript function based on viewport visibility works on desktop but not on smartphones?

Tags: javascript, bounding

I'm having trouble with some Javascript I used for a site.
The aim was to have a header elements css changes based on the appearance on screen of a specific div.
Actually it works just perfectly on desktop ! But not on Iphones...
I can't figure out what's wrong with it...
Can you help me understand this ?
Thanks alotlotlot !

```
var isInViewport = function (elem) {
    var bounding = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        bounding.top >= 0 &&
        bounding.left >= 0 &&
        bounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
};
var section_clouds = document.querySelector('#section_intro_clouds');
window.addEventListener('transitionend', function (event) {
    if (isInViewport(section_clouds)) {
        document.getElementById('header_blanc').classList.add('colorer_bleu');}
else {document.getElementById('header_blanc').classList.remove('colorer_bleu');}
}, false);
```

Comment: I know I'm not answering your question, but if your goal is to modify CSS based on screen sizes, you don't need any JavaScript at all: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't do it using just CSS and media queries, it's more complicated than that. To be more precise : my header is fixed and I want it to match color with a section inside a sliding element below (inside the content). I can't solve it with css then. That's why I used javascript and it actually worked. The class “colorer_bleu“ changes all the desired elements of my header only when the corresponding section appears below the header.
But still not working on smartphones...
Is it because of the bounding “screen-size detection“ syntax ?

Comment: It's hard to tell from the snippet. We can't reproduce the issue with the code given. I'm not even sure your `transitionend` event is firing.

Comment: According to MDN _"Safari for iOS will modify the effective viewport based on the user zoom. This results in incorrect values whenever the user has zoomed"_ so maybe that's your issue .https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect#Browser_compatibility

Comment: It might be it, I tried using no zoom but it didn't fix the problem